# C# Custom Copy constructor, copy events

Tags: c#, reflection, copy-constructor

I'm trying to create a copy constructor for my C# object using reflection.  I am able to copy all of the fields and properties (those are easy) but I'm having some issues copying the Events.

Is there a way to (via reflection) copy all of the delegates that have subscribed to an event from one object to another?  (Both will be the same type)

Thank you :)

Comment: C# wasn't designed to have copy constructors; have you tried `ICloneable.Clone()` and `Object.MemberwiseClone()`?

Comment: I was thinking about implementing those interfaces, but I wanted a very generic constructor, because I'm implementing this on a class that gets inherited by several other classes.  As for Copy Constructor, this isn't like the C++ cctor, it's just a constructor that takes an object with the same base type and clones it.  The reason I'm do this is because the class also needs to be disposed, so if I'm going to need an item that persists, instead of redoing the whole dispose timing, making a copy of the object seemed easier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will entirely depend on the implementation. After all, an event can be implemented any way you want. If you're using a *field-like event* then you should be able to just copy the field value:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

    public Test(Test other)
    {
        this.SomeEvent = other.SomeEvent;
    }
}
```

This is fine as delegates are immutable - subscribing to an event creates a new delegate and assigns that to the field, so your two objects would be independent. If the event was implemented using something like [`EventHandlerList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist.aspx) you would want to create a clone rather than using simple field assignment.

EDIT: To do this with reflection, you'd simply use the fields like any other. Field-like events are simply events backed by fields. If you're already copying all the fields within a class, you won't have any extra work to do.

Be aware that unless you go to extra effort, you'll only make a *shallow* copy - for example, if you have a field of type `List<string>`, your new object will refer to the same object as the old object, so any changes to the list will be seen via both objects.

Comment: Yes, all of the events are field like.  But how do I do this via reflection?

Comment: Sweet! Thanks :) I've got the original object, the new object, and the EventInfo for the Event.  I just haven't gotten the event to be added from the original to the new.

Comment: It took a bit of work to get the actual delegate but once I got it, I was able to call field.AddEventHandler(copyObject, del); where del was the delegate of the event and copyObject is the new instance.

Comment: @joe_coolish: I don't understand why you'd bother. Why aren't you just copying the field ignoring the fact that it's backing an event?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: All I have is the EventInfo item, not the actual field. I don't have the actual field because I implemented this Copy function in a Base class. I wanted the Copy to work in all of the derived classes, which would mean I wouldn't have knowledge of all of the fields.

if there is a way to copy the field using the EventInfo item, I'll use that.  But what I had worked.  I say "had" because I ended up scrapping everything and going with Object.MemberwiseClone().  I had to modify some things in the Base class, but in the end it worked better.

Comment: @joe_coolish: If you don't have knowledge of all the fields, how are you going to cope with any *other* fields within the subclass? Basically once you've solved that, you'll have solved the field-like events issue.